# How do I check whether an environment variable is set in PHP?

Tags: php, environment-variables, isset

In PHP, how do I test whether an environment variable is set? I would like behavior like this:

```
// Assuming MYVAR isn't defined yet.
isset(MYVAR); // returns false
putenv("MYVAR=foobar");
isset(MYVAR); // returns true
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`getenv()` returns `false` if the environment variable is not set. The following code will work:

```
// Assuming MYVAR isn't defined yet.
getenv("MYVAR") !== false; // returns false
putenv("MYVAR=foobar");
getenv("MYVAR") !== false; // returns true
```

Be sure to use the strict comparison operator (`!==`) because `getenv()` normally returns a string that could be cast as a boolean.

Comment: I don't know why, but my PHP (7.1.32) returns an empty string when MYVAR is not defined... I tried`key_exists('MYVAR', getenv())`, but it didn't work either, so I ended up checking for `!empty(getenv('MYVAR'))`...

Comment: For people using DotEnv: values of OFF will be a string and so evaluate to  `true` with this approach.

Comment: What happened if my env variable `ENV_VARIABLE=false`  ?

Comment: @Al-Amin Environment variables are always strings, so setting it to false will result in a string "false".

Answer (score 4):

you can check like this

```
if($ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
echo $ip;
```

[getenv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)() Returns the value of the environment variable.

Comment: Isn't `REMOTE_ADDR` always set? In my case, I'm writing a script that needs to act differently based on whether the server has an environment variable set.

Comment: @wecsam REMOTE_ADDR was just an example you can pass different environment variable

Comment: I figured out by myself that `getenv()` returns `false` if the environment variable is not set. I see that that is what your code tries to illustrate. However, there are several problems with your code. First of all, we try to avoid using the `=` assignment operator in `if` conditionals because we almost always meant `==`. Second of all, the value of the environment variable could be an empty string that casts to `false`,  so we need to use a strict comparison operator.

Comment: @wecsam I think its not comparison ,assign getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') value to $ip and then checking for $ip   .

Comment: I know that it's not a comparison. What I'm saying is that we usually don't do assignments in `if` conditionals.

Comment: @wescam is right, you can't do assignment inside an if condition

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables (at least in PHP) are always strings. It is not possible to set them to boolean `false` - that's why `putenv()` only accepts one string as a parameter. So whenever `getenv()` returns `false` the environment variable is not set. Knowing this you can find out if an environment variable is set by strictly comparing it against `false`.

```php
if ( getenv('MYVAR') !== false ) {
    echo 'Environment variable "MYVAR" is set to "' . getenv('MYVAR') . '"';
}
```

Here are some tests (using the Apache directive `SetEnv`):

```
SetEnv TEST_FALSE false
SetEnv TEST_QUOTED_FALSE "false"
SetEnv TEST_0 0
SetEnv TEST_QUOTED_0 "0"
SetEnv TEST_EMPTY
SetEnv TEST_QUOTED_EMPTY ""
```

and PHP `putenv()`:

```php
putenv("PUTENV_FALSE=false");
putenv("PUTENV_0=0");
putenv("PUTENV_EMPTY=");
```

what will result in:

```
UNSET_ENV:         bool(false)
TEST_FALSE:        string(5) "false"
TEST_QUOTED_FALSE: string(5) "false"
TEST_0:            string(1) "0"
TEST_QUOTED_0:     string(1) "0"
TEST_EMPTY:        string(0) ""
TEST_QUOTED_EMPTY: string(0) ""
PUTENV_FALSE:      string(5) "false"
PUTENV_0:          string(1) "0"
PUTENV_EMPTY:      string(0) ""
```

**Not asked here, but related to it:**
If you want to check an environment variable if it is set to boolean true, you could use the filter functions:

```php
filter_var( getenv('MYVAR'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) );
```

Because when using this filter, the result would look like that:

```
UNSET_ENV:         bool(false)
TEST_FALSE:        bool(false)
TEST_QUOTED_FALSE: bool(false)
TEST_0:            bool(false)
TEST_QUOTED_0:     bool(false)
TEST_EMPTY:        bool(false)
TEST_QUOTED_EMPTY: bool(false)
PUTENV_FALSE:      bool(false)
PUTENV_0:          bool(false)
PUTENV_EMPTY:      bool(false)
```

Where values like "true", "on", "yes" and "1" (all case insensitive) would result in `bool(true)`. Any other string is returning a `bool(false)`.

Answer (score -7):

This is what you need

```
    $var = getenv(MYVAR)
    if(isset($var)) {

    } else {

    }
```

Comment: `isset($var)` is always true in this case.

Comment: Since getvar() returns false when not set, isset will return true always, since $var is set, but set to false.